# Powering aAdafruit PiTFT 2.4" HAT Mini Kit - 320x240 TFT Touchscreen. via a power bank. (Needs a bit more power)

Tags: power, display, battery, lcd

I've been having problems getting this set up and now I do believe I know why.

I got an Anker Power Bank (26,800mah) Not the Power Core +

Input: 5V ⎓ 4A (5V ⎓ 2A Max Per Port)

Output: 5V ⎓ 6A (5V ⎓ 3A Max Per Port)

and I need a bit more power for the screen to work (uses 3.3a)

I think it's a dual USB cable and a micro USB (ALL IN ONE) that I need (so I can get more amps from the power bank to the PI) but I have no idea whatsoever.

Which exact cable would I need?

I am using a PI 3 Model 3B+

I could use a plug but it's power bank only I want.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use this cable. It’s wired in parallel to provide 5 volts and can provide the full amperage needed.

https://www.startech.com/en-us/cables/usb2hauby1

Startech part USB2HAUBY1

Comment: Thanks. I did look at that one. I presume you use that cable?                               5 volts from each USB cable?

Comment: I have used one. Each cable provides 5 volts, but since they’re wired in parallel, they provide 5 volts total. Also because they’re wired in parallel, they will allow your setup to draw current from both ports, or up to 6 amps total.